# Magento Navigation How To Keep on One Line

Tags: magento2, theme, menu, navigation, topmenu

This seems like something simple, but just not working for me. I'm trying to change my styles.css to have the navigation stay on one line. Here is the code I think is relevant.

```
/********** < Navigation */
.nav-container {clear: both; width:70%; float: left; margin: 10px 0px 10px  }
#nav { margin:0 auto; padding:0; font-size:13px; }

/* All Levels */ /* Style consistent throughout all nav levels */
#nav li { position:relative; text-align:left; }
#nav li.over { z-index:998; }
#nav a,
#nav a:hover { display:block; line-height:1.3em; text-decoration:none; }
#nav span { display:block; cursor:pointer; white-space:nowrap; }
#nav li ul span {white-space:normal; }
#nav ul li.parent a {}
#nav ul li.parent li a { background-image:none; }
#nav a.category span { background: url(../images/nav-category.gif) no-repeat center right; padding-right: 20px; }

/* 0 Level */
#nav li { float:left; }
#nav li.active a { color:#2882ce; }
#nav a { font-size: 115%; float:left; padding:5px 50px 5px 0px; color:#303030; }
#nav li.last a { padding-right: 0px !important;}
#nav li.over a,
#nav a:hover { color:#2882ce; }

/* 1st Level */
#nav ul li,
#nav ul li.active { float:none; margin:0; padding-bottom:1px; background:#ecf3f6; }
#nav ul li.last { background:#ecf3f6; padding-bottom:0; }

#nav ul a,
#nav ul a:hover { float:none; padding:0; background:none; }
#nav ul li a { font-size: 100% !important; font-weight:normal !important; }

/* 2nd Level */
#nav ul,
#nav div { position:absolute; width:15em; top:27px; left:-10000px; border:1px solid #899ba5; }
#nav div ul { position:static; width:auto; border:none; }

/* 3rd+ Level */
#nav ul ul,
#nav ul div { top:5px; }

#nav ul li a { background:#ecf3f6; }
#nav ul li a:hover { background:#d5e4eb; }
#nav ul li a,
#nav ul li a:hover { color:#2f2f2f !important; }
#nav ul span,
#nav ul li.last li span { padding:3px 15px 4px 15px; }

/* Show menu */
#nav li ul.shown-sub,
#nav li div.shown-sub { left:0; z-index:999; }
#nav li .shown-sub ul.shown-sub,
#nav li .shown-sub li div.shown-sub { left:100px; }
/********** Navigation > */
```

Comment: Our is it in another location? possibly topemnu.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix my problem, tried multiple things like dispay: (table,inline,block-line, etc..) I also changed the width to 100% as opposed to 70%. What fixed the problem was

```
.nav-container {clear: both; width:1800px
```

I just changed the width size to px instead of using %, fixed the problem :). Just adding a answer just in case anyone else has the same issue.